# Does there exist a natural number $a$ such that $a^2+1$ is divisble by $9$?

Tags: factoring

Can the above question be solved? Or can it be proved that it can not be solved?

What is the best approach to solving such questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $a$ and suppose $9$ divides $a^2+1$. Then so does $3$. This means that
$$a^2+1 \equiv 0 \mod{3}$$

and this cannot happen, since squares modulo $3$ are just $0$ and $1$.

So there are no integers $a$ such that $9$ divides $a^2+1$.

Comment: Why is $a^2 \mod 3 \not = 2$?

Comment: $0^2 = 0$, $1^2=1$, $2^2=4 \equiv 1$. So squares are never $2 \mod{3}$

Comment: So that much is enough to conclude so? Okay, I didn't know. Thank you.